# Is there another event in ext.js I should use?

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have a column with text and an image. I am trying to add an event to the image. The id is assigned dynamically. When I try to bind the event, the Ext.get("id") is returning a null. I can see renderer running after viewready because the screen is refreshing. Should I try different DOM events?

```
  {
        text: 'My Thing',
        flex: 6,
        sortable: true,
        width: 40,
        dataIndex: 'myThing',
        renderer: function (val, metaData, record, rowIdx, colIdx, store, view) {
           {console.log(evname, arguments);});
                var returnStr = '<div>' + val + '</div>' + '<img id="image_' + record.data.myItem.id + '" src="/myThing/img/icon.png"/>';
                console.log(returnStr);
                return returnStr;
        }


console.log('Im here');
        for(var j=0; j<items.length; j++){
            console.log(j)
            var itemDesc = 'image_' + items[j].data.myItem.id;
            var itemDescStr = items[j].data.lineItem.myItem.id;
            console.log('itemDesc' + itemDesc)
            console.log(Ext.get(itemDesc));
            (function(itemDescStr) {
                Ext.get(itemDesc).on('click', function(e,t){
                    console.log('image '+ itemDescStr + ' clicked');
                });
            })(itemDescStr);
        }
```

"Ext.get(itemDesc)" is returning a null.

Edit:

My temporary solution was this:

```
 {
        text: 'My Thing',
        flex: 6,
        sortable: true,
        width: 40,
        dataIndex: 'myThing'
        renderer: function (val, metaData, record, rowIdx, colIdx, store, view) {
            var returnStr = '<div><img id="image_' + record.data.myItem.id;
                returnStr = returnStr + '" src="/myApp/resources/app/img/myIcon.gif" ';
            returnStr = returnStr + 'onclick="Ext.foo(' + rowIdx + ')" />';
            returnStr = returnStr + ' ' + val + '</div>';
            return returnStr;
        }
    },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't do it like that, use event delegation:

```
Ext.onReady(function() {

    var grid = new Ext.grid.Panel({
        width: 400,
        height: 400,
        renderTo: document.body,
        store: {
            fields: ['name'],
            data: [{
                name: 'Foo'
            }, {
                name: 'Bar'
            }]
        },
        columns: [{
            dataIndex: 'name',
            renderer: function(v) {
                return Ext.String.format('<div class="x">{0}</div><div class="y">{0}</div><div class="z">{0}</div>', v);
            }
        }],
        listeners: {
            cellclick: function(view, el, cellIdx, record, row, rowIdx, e) {
                if (e.getTarget('.x')) {
                    console.log('x');
                } else if (e.getTarget('.y')) {
                    console.log('y');
                } else {
                    console.log('neither');
                }
            }
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: Thank you, but I need for there to be an image in the cell. And that image has to have a tooltip for that specific row.

Comment: Above is a sample of how you'd go about doing such a thing. Just modify it slightly.

Comment: Thank you so much! We were trying to make this so an onclick event is attached to the image. I put that function in the image tag, and defined the function in viewReady.